# Vue style is not being applied

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am facing a strange problem in which the style in my vue component is not being compiled and applied along with the template and script.

I've included my code below. The intention is to animate a slide fade on the hidden text when I click the button. The actual result is the text becomes visible but the css is not applied to it.

---

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="show = !show">
      Click Me
    </button>
    <transition name="slide-fade">
      <p class="test-style" v-if="show">This is a hidden message.</p>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        show: false,
      };
    },
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  .test-style {
    color: red;
  }
  .slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }
  .slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
  }
  .slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(10px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

---

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

### Edit - Aug 10th, 2020

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "www",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: did you try it out without `scoped`?

Comment: it should work check this https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-x9rno

Comment: It works in the sandbox for me too, so maybe it's got something to do with the browser not supporting the styles?

Comment: Hmm. I'm wondering if its a problem with how webpack is building it. My package.json file doesn't look anything like yours BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: I added my package.json file. I'm gonna try to use the package.json file that you included in your sandbox to see if that fixes anything. Also yes I had already tried it without `scoped`.

Comment: I just tried moving the style into a css file and it works when I do it that way. So why can't I get it to work with vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OKAAAY I finally figured it out. The problem was with the `packages.json` `devDependencies`. Specifically the `css-loader` version `^4.2.1` must somehow be corrupt or super buggy. I changed the version to `^2.1.0` and now the style is loaded just fine and with the `scoped` param. Thank you Boussadjra Brahim for setting up the sandbox, that was very helpful in my problem-solving.

Answer (score 0):

I am just learning VueJS 3 along with Larave 8 and I was experimenting the same problem, but it was because I didn't run the

> npm run dev

command in the console.